# How to rename observations in different columns in different dataframes in R?

Tags: r, rename

I want to add "Name" to the start and "plc" to the end of the names of the observations in different columns in different dataframes, **except** where the names already have "Name" or "plc" in the right place. The following is a simple reprex.

**Original dataframes**

```
names1a <- c("Name Alperton plc", "Bury", "Central", "Durham")
names1b <- c("Egham plc", "Fulton", "Great", "Heywood plc")
year1 <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2001)
df1 <- data.frame(names1a, names1b, year1)

names2 <- c("Charleton plc", "Birmingham", "Name Tees", "Salford")
year2 <- c(2000, 1955, 2001, 2001)
df2 <- data.frame(names2, year2)
```

**Desired result:**

df1

```
            names1a          names1b year1
1 Name Alperton plc   Name Egham plc  1999
2     Name Bury plc  Name Fulton plc  2000
3  Name Central plc   Name Great plc  2001
4   Name Durham plc Name Heywood plc  2001
```

df2

```
               names2 year2
1  Name Charleton plc  2000
2 Name Birmingham plc  1955
3       Name Tees plc  2001
4    Name Salford plc  2001
```

**My approach:** I get the result I want, but I have a large dataset with many columns, so my approach is just too repetitive. I struggle with making functions and I think one would be useful here:

```
df1$names1a <- sub("$", " plc", df1$names1a)
df1$names1b <- sub("$", " plc", df1$names1b)
df2$names2 <- sub("$", " plc", df2$names2)
df1$names1a <- sub("plc plc", "plc", df1$names1a)
df1$names1b <- sub("plc plc", "plc", df1$names1b)
df2$names2 <- sub("plc plc", "plc", df2$names2)

df1$names1a <- sub("^", "Name ", df1$names1a)
df1$names1b <- sub("^", "Name ", df1$names1b)
df2$names2 <- sub("^", "Name ", df2$names2)
df1$names1a <- sub("Name Name", "Name", df1$names1a)
df1$names1b <- sub("Name Name", "Name", df1$names1b)
df2$names2 <- sub("Name Name", "Name", df2$names2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to delete "Name" and "plc" and add it to everything afterwards, like so:

```
f <- function(x) paste("Name", trimws(gsub("^Name|plc$", "", x)), "plc")

cols <- c("names1a", "names1b")
df1[cols] <- lapply(df1[cols], f)
df1
#          names1a         names1b year1
# 1 Name Arton plc    Name Egh plc  1999
# 2  Name Bury plc  Name Futon plc  2000
# 3  Name Cntr plc    Name Grt plc  2001
# 4  Name Durh plc Name Hywood plc  2001

df2$names2 <- f(df2$names2)
df2
#             names2 year2
# 1  Name Chrton plc  2000
# 2 Name Biringh plc  1955
# 3      Name Ts plc  2001
# 4   Name Sford plc  2001
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this function which allows editing both data frames separately and can cope with any number of columns starting with "names...". Based on `tidyverse` packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

  fun <- function(df){
    df <-
      df %>% 
      mutate(across(starts_with("names"), ~ str_replace_all(., "^Name | plc$", "")),
             across(starts_with("names"), ~ paste("Name", .,  "plc")))
    return(df)
  }
  
fun(df = df1)
#>             names1a          names1b year1
#> 1 Name Alperton plc   Name Egham plc  1999
#> 2     Name Bury plc  Name Fulton plc  2000
#> 3  Name Central plc   Name Great plc  2001
#> 4   Name Durham plc Name Heywood plc  2001
  
fun(df2)
#>                names2 year2
#> 1  Name Charleton plc  2000
#> 2 Name Birmingham plc  1955
#> 3       Name Tees plc  2001
#> 4    Name Salford plc  2001
```

You could combine the two mutate functions into one:

`mutate(across(starts_with("names"), ~ paste("Name", str_replace_all(., "^Name | plc$", ""),  "plc")))`

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the confounding strings from the names first and then append 'name' and 'plc' however you like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

names1a <- c("Name Alperton plc", "Bury", "Central", "Durham")

names1a <- str_replace_all(names1a, "Name ", "")
names1a <- str_replace_all(names1a, " plc", "")
names1a <- paste0("Name ", names1a, " plc")

names1a
#> [1] "Name Alperton plc" "Name Bury plc"     "Name Central plc" 
#> [4] "Name Durham plc"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>